# Delete multiple rows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ubuntu

I have a 'notifications app' in my program.  In the app there is an 'notices' section.  Each notice has an option to delete the notice with a delete button on that row.  The 'notices' section also has a clear button.  I want to make that clear button delete all of the notices in the 'notices' section.  However I am having trouble doing this.

CONTROLLER

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
 .module('notifications')
 .controller('NotificationsCtrl', NotificationsCtrl);

function NotificationsCtrl($scope, $state, SecService, Service, RecService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.ctrlName = 'NotificationsCtrl';

  $scope.showAppsMenu = false;

  $scope.appList = {};

  $scope.dismissNotification = function(notification) {
    EcosystemService.dismissNotification(notification.id).then(
      function (response) {
        delete     $scope.appList[notification.appId].notifications[notification.id];
      });
  };

  $scope.dismissAppNotifications = function(app) {
var notifications = app.notifications;
for (var i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++) {
  EcosystemService.dismissNotification(notifications[i].id).then(
    function(index) {
        return function (response) {
          delete app.notifications[index];
        }
    }(i));
}
};
```

I need to make a change in `$scope.dismissAppNotifications`.  I am just stumped on what I need to add.  The 'alerts' are not being cleared still.  I added where the `Service` is being used.  Maybe I need to add something here as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - you want to delete all notifications within one app - so iterating over appList is not necessary. Iterate over one app's notifications instead:

```
$scope.dismissAppNotifications = function(app) {
    var notifications = app.notifications;
    for (var id in notifications) {
      // may be reasonable to add checking for only own properties
      EcosystemService.dismissNotification(notifications[id].id).then(
        function(notificationId) { // outer function needed because of the way scopes and closures works in js
            return function (response) {
              delete app.notifications[notificationId];
            }
        }(id));
    }
};
```

`notifications[id].id` can be replaced with simply `id` if key and id property are the same.

Comment: I understand what you did there.  I tried to correct my code and then run it, but it still isn't deleting all the 'alerts'.  When I click the button nothing happens.  I debugged, but still can't seem to determine what is wrong with the code...

Comment: Does dismissing single notification work? Notifications property is an array or object?

Comment: Can you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(app)))` at the beginning of the function and tell me what's printed in browser's console? Also, what's `notification.id` - is it index of the notification in the list?

Comment: I also add a picture from when I was debugging.

Comment: Ok, now I see that `notifications` is an object and I'm iterating over it like it was an array. I'll update my answer in few minutes.

Comment: Yes notifications is an object.  Sorry I didn't make that clear.